# Manage email addresses on a GAE custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine

More than a year ago, I associated a custom domain (purchased from GoDaddy) with the GAE application for which I am the lead developer and administrator. At that time, Google also required me to associate some email addresses with that domain. Those email addresses are hosted by Google, not by GoDaddy.

But up till now, no one on our team has used those email addresses, and now I've forgotten what email addresses I set up, much less any passwords for them.

And I can't find the admin page that I used to set them up, or whatever admin page GAE/Google now uses to show the list of email addresses associated with the domain, as well as to administer them (for example, set up passwords, view their inboxes, add or delete email addresses, etc.)

I'd appreciate a link to the GAE/Google page that would show the list of email addresses for our custom domain, and enable us to administer them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom domain settings for App Engine are available at:  https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains

Select the project associated with the domain.  However, I don't know of an inbox service available for individual users in GAE - only email directly to an API.

If this was a Google for Work (now G Suite) domain, use the link below to manage users and emails for that domain.

https://admin.google.com/

Comment: Hi, Jeff. Neither "Google for Work" nor "G Suite" sound like familiar entities from the time I established the accounts, but the second link you supplied seems to have the info I was looking for. Thanks!.